# Custom greeting when I log in via ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I need to create a custom greeting message on my server when I log in via ssh. Or at least I want to add some information to it. I have none of these files: /etc/ssh/sshd_config, /etc/motd. So how can I do that?

Comment: When **you** log in, or when anyone logs in? If you want something when you log in, just add an `echo` to `~/.profile`

Comment: @Patrick That is very bad idea to write something in `~/.profile`. It breaks a lot of protocols, such as `sftp`, when they do net expect that.

Comment: @Jakuje it's very easy to put in a check such as `if [ -t 1 ]; ...`, which i would recommend doing anyway, even without things like sftp

Answer (score 2):

For displaying message before successful login:

vim /etc/yourmessage.txt

```
<yourcontent here>  save/exit
```

vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Banner /etc/yourmessage.txt
```

Displaying message after users successfully login:-

```
#create the file /etc/motd 
vim /etc/motd
    <your content here> save/exit
```

you have to install openssh-server on your server if you `dont have sshd_config`.

if on debian/ubuntu :-

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```

for centos/redhat

```
yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients
```